# How to use Eclipse plugins inside regular Java project?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a EMF project with an Ecore model, and I exported it as an Eclipse Plugin. Now I want to reuse this plugin (the plugin exported Java packages) inside a regular Java project (using Eclipse).

I created a Java project, and tried to use the option `Build Path > Add Libraries > Plugin Dependencies` but it shows an empty plugin list and I cant add entries.

The created Java project have no `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` and I have not found a way to create it automatically.

How can I add a dependency to my exported plugin? Do I need to create a special kind of project?

Comment: The interesting question here is whether your runtime is based on OSGi or is a "plain" Java JRE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `Plugin Project`. So you can edit your `MANIFEST.MF` and add the generated plugin as a dependency.

Lars Vogel has a [good tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseEMF/article.html#javacode) that covers how to do it in EMF context.